# VS2015 cannot find unit tests

Tags: visual-studio-2015

My computer has been through a lot.  Many versions and components of Visual Studio and SQL Server 2008 through 2016 have come on and off of my computer.  It now appears that Visual Studio 2015 is unable to find unit tests.  I have confirmed on a colleagues computer that these unit tests are working fine.

When I attempt to run unit tests, the output is:

```
------ Discover test started ------
========== Discover test finished: 0 found (0:00:00.1970591) ==========
```

This is true for both MSUnit and xUnit.  I have the xUnit runner installed.

I tried to strip VS2015 completely off of the computer, but some of the uninstallers are faulty and don't do their job.  When I reinstall VS2015 Pro, it is still defective.  Is there a persistent setting that's causing my grief?

At this point I've booked to have my computer reimaged.  I'm still very curious how this could be caused or fixed.